# Disable tag photos alert on android emulator

Tags: android, adb, emulation

Who knows how disable "Remember photo locations?" alert on android emulator?

[image: Alert]

It is appearing after accept/deny location request by camera.
After click "Next" button emulator is hanging and can't go out from camera.
How to avoid it?